# Wrong login opens a session too

Tags: php, sqlite, session, authentication

I have written this login php based in sqlite:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db');

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 4 < time()) {
        session_destroy();
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['pass']    = "";
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
}
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['pass'])) {

    $result = $db->query("SELECT password,user FROM users");
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if (password_verify($_SESSION['pass'], $row['password'])) {
            echo "Welcome! You're logged in " . $row['user'] . "!  <a href='index.php?logout=true'>logout</a>";
            if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
                unset($_SESSION['pass']);
                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }
    }

}

else {
    echo '<form method="POST" action=""><input type="password" name="pass"><form>';
}
?>
```

This is my sqlite (data.db):

[image]

MY PROBLEM IS THE FOLLOWING: If I login with one of the users in the database, the session is supossed to last 4 seconds, and you can read the message: Hello user, you're logged in (logout).

BUT: If I introduce a mistaken password (which is not in the database), the screen turns white and I have to wait for 4 seconds too.

MY QUESTION IS: How can I redirect wrong logins to the login form with no need to wait for the session to finish?

Comment: You are just looping through all users. You should be checking the password matches with a specific user.

Comment: I've been tryin to place the login code in several places in the php sheet but i dont know how to do it. Could you help me?

Comment: Can you format the code and provide the DB structure? Are you only storing passwords?

Comment: @chris85 changed the question above to show you that information

Comment: Okay, and you are planning to pass the `user` in the form?

Comment: no, its just a trial and it just asks for password. My problem is that, when login fails (wrong password) you have to wait for the session to expire to go back to the form page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102856/discussion-between-chris85-and-kathlyn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic seemed a bit off to me I would do take this approach:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db');
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // if logout is set just log them out no need for other conditionals
    unset($_SESSION['pass']);
    header('location: index.php');
    exit(); //exit after header otherwise page keeps processing
}
if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
     if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 4 < time()) {
        session_destroy();
     }
//} else {
//   $_SESSION['pass']   = "";
//   $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
//}
//if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
//   $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
}
if (!empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $result = $db->query("SELECT password,user FROM users");
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $row['password'])) {
            echo "Welcome! You're logged in " . $row['user'] . "!  <a href='index.php?logout=true'>logout</a>";
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
            $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
        }
    }
}
if(empty($_SESSION['pass'])) {
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit">
<form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Additionally you also really should pass the user's name that you are testing the password against. This method will require long loads when you have more users. It also won't work accurately when 2 users have the same password.